# Change background color of GoogleMap.Map_Type_None

Tags: android, google-maps

Is there a way, to change the standard grey background color of google maps, if the map type is selected as Map_Type_None.

Thanks for help

Comment: Overlay your own tile but you can't simple change the color of grey tiles because Google map is on top of your view group hierarchy!

Comment: Thanks for your tip. It works, I just had to lift all my other paintings on the map 1 level up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to do this.

1. Add a custom overlay to the map.
2. Change the hierarchy of your layout(View Group), so that google map will be below other views!

Comment: Can you show how to do it, please?